# Jest + Mongoose: Have to run find twice to get results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jestjs

I am building tests for my node/express controller methods and using `@shelf/jest-mongodb`. I am creating a document first, and then when I try to find that I have to run find twice from model in order to get the results. It should get the results in the first find instead.

**test.js**

```
const { Subscription } = require('../src/models/subscription.schemaModel'); // model
const {
  createSubscription,
} = require('../src/controllers/subscription.controller');

const subData = {...};

beforeAll(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(

    process.env.MONGO_URL,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    }
  );
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});

describe('creates a subscription ', () => {
  it('can be created correctly', async () => {
    const sub = await createSubscription(subData);
    await Subscription.find(); // if I comment out this line, I would get 0 results.
    const subs = await Subscription.find();
    expect(subs[0].items[0].sku).toBe(233234);
  });
});
```

**subscription.controller.js**

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Subscription } = require('../models/subscription.schemaModel');
const isTestEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test';

module.exports.createSubscription = async (data) => {
  try {
    let error = null;
    const doc = new Subscription(data);
    doc.accountId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(doc.accountId);

    await doc.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(`createSubscription saving ${err}`);
        error = err;
      }
    });

    if (!error) {
      logger.info(
        `Subscription created =>  id: ${doc._id} store: ${doc.store}`
      );
      return doc;
    } else {
      return error;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`createSubscription ${err}`);
  }
};
```

The **schemaModel** file essentially contains the schema and exports model. Everything seems to work fine if I would do all the operations in the test file (schema+model+controller module)which defeats the purpose of testing my modules but not if I am importing. In this case I would have to run `find()` twice to get the results.

I have been trying multiple things from what I could find from googling, but no luck! Any help or lead would be appreciated. Also let me know if you need any other details.
Thank you!!

Comment: Did you try to add random delay instead of find()? I don't see a place for race conditions here but this doesn't mean they don't exist. createSubscription contains flaky callback-based error handling but I doubt this is the problem here.

Comment: @EstusFlask you mean like a timeout? No, and I don't think that is a good idea anyway. Not the issue on the error handling, I feel like it is more on the model since when I tried doing everything on the test file, it would work as supposed too but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yes, `await new Promise(...setTmeout...)`. It's not a good idea but could give an idea what's going on. I have no explanation specifically for additional `find()` itself. Try to use `await doc.save()` instead. My point this that a callback could affect control flow and make createSubscription return too soon. I believe this is not how Mongoose works but such behaviour occurs in combined promise/callback APIs. Yes, it can depend on a model too. It doesn't have hooks/middlewares, does it?

Comment: @EstusFlask I see, I did a delay as suggested and now it's getting results as it should without having to do `find()` twice. I do have an `await` on `doc.save()` and no hooks/middlewares on model/schema. 

Seems like some sort of race condition.. but don't get it why...any idea in your mind?

Comment: I meant `await doc.save()` with no args. I suspect that's because of save callback, because everything else looks ok. In some APIs that support both callbacks and promises, the use of a callback nullifies a promise, but I don't remember if it's true for Mongoose. Any way, that callback looks odd, the use of callbacks and promises is mutually exclusive in such cases.

Comment: God damn it, that was the case!!! @EstusFlask bravo! I didn't know that and wouldn't have guessed! whee!  Let me see how can I handle that error!

Comment: Yes, refactored that module!! Thank you again. Put the answer if you want and I will make sure to approve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that posted code contains is that Mongoose promise API is mixed with legacy callback API. It appears that `save` results in race condition that is has been circumvented by random delay that extra `find` provides.

Although Mongoose documentation mentions that methods unconditionally return promises, a common pattern for JavaScript APIs that support both promises and callbacks is to enable promise control flow by omitting callback argument, and vice versa. This is most likely what happens here.

A way to avoid race conditions in such cases is to stick to promise control flow, e.g.:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
 try {
  await mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_URL,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  )
 } catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
   process.exit(1);
 }
});
```